# has_many through, with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Tag model:

```
name:string
user_tag: boolean
private_tag: boolean
```

and a Picture model with a simple join table (picture_id, tag_id)

I want to have picture.tags, picture.user_tags, and picture.private_tags why does the following code not work and how should I fix it?

```
has_many :tags, -> { where :private_tag => false and :user_tag => false }, through: :pictures_tags
has_many :private_tags, -> { where :private_tag => true }, through: :pictures_tags
has_many :user_tags, -> { where :user_tag => true }, through: :pictures_tags
```

!!EDIT!!

So I got it not work here:

```
has_many :tags, through: :pictures_tags, :source => :tag, :conditions => ['tags.private_tag = ? and tags.user_tag = ?', false, false]
has_many :private_tags, through: :pictures_tags, :source => :tag, :conditions => ['tags.private_tag = ?', true]
has_many :user_tags, through: :pictures_tags, :source => :tag, :conditions => ['tags.user_tag = ?', true]
```

But it seems to be returning twice.

```
2.1.1 :036 > picture = Picture.last
Picture Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" ORDER BY "pictures"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Picture id: 378, user_id: 35, picture: "i6.JPG", created_at: "2014-11-23 12:19:35", 
updated_at:"2014-11-23 12:19:35", number_of_votes: 0, number_of_upvotes: 0, 
blurb: "!test @test #test"> 
2.1.1 :037 > picture.private_tags
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "pictures_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "pictures_tags"."tag_id" WHERE (tags.private_tag = 't') AND "pictures_tags"."picture_id" = ?  [["picture_id", 378]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
[#<Tag id: 198, name: "!test", created_at: "2014-11-23 12:19:35", updated_at: "2014-11-23 12:19:35",
private_tag: true, user_tag: false>, #<Tag id: 198, name: "!test", created_at: "2014-11-23 12:19:35", 
updated_at: "2014-11-23 12:19:35", private_tag: true, user_tag: false>]>
2.1.1 :038 > picture.private_tags.count
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "pictures_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "pictures_tags"."tag_id" WHERE (tags.private_tag = 't') AND "pictures_tags"."picture_id" = ?  [["picture_id", 378]]
 => 2
```

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? The former (with scopes) is for 4.x and the latter (with conitions) is 3.2.

Comment: What does `pictures.pictures_tags` look like? Do you see duplicates in this table?

Answer (score 1):

You'er likely having issues with syntax. These associations:

```
has_many :private_tags, -> { where :private_tag => true }, through: :pictures_tags
has_many :user_tags, -> { where :user_tag => true }, through: :pictures_tags
```

are fine. The problem is with:

```
has_many :tags, -> { where :private_tag => false and :user_tag => false }, through: :pictures_tags
```

because `where` clause does not take a condition as an argument (it is not a valid condition either), but a `Hash`. So it would be:

```
has_many :tags, -> { where :private_tag => false, :user_tag => false }, through: :pictures_tags
```

Comment: Let's stay with scopes, as it's Rails 4 valid approach.

Comment: yep, i cast `unclear what you're asking` because i do not understand what the question and OP nothing say about wrong syntax.